# I'm getting notified of chat messages from ignored users

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, ignored-users

If I add a troll to the chat's ignore list, can we make it so that they don't show up in the SE Network inbox when they ping me?

If I have it set up like this:

[image]

I shouldn't be seeing this:

[image]

Comment: I believe this has happened to me as well, although not recently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It should be excluding you from their replied and mentions. I'll get this hacked in. I'm sure it did this previously - it must have evaporated at some change to the code. But yes - your expectation is reasonable.