# Ignored users still appear in the 'other rooms you're in' message preview

Tags: bug, chat, sidebar, ignored-users

Well it might not be a huge issue to some (I suppose it depends on how you use the chat system) but when I "Ignore this user everywhere", their messages still appear on the sidebar for the 'other rooms you're in' if they say something. Albeit I can ignore this feature and the text within it, I just find it odd that I can still see it.

This is only a nuisance when you truly are annoyed by a user and ignoring them in the chat was the best possible alternative to leaving the room or starting an argument (no references here, but any long time chat user has been annoyed by some help vampire at one point in time or another and would just prefer to ignore them for good).

If you have no clue to the sidebar or preview I'm talking about: this is for you,

[image]

I have chosen to *Ignore this user everywhere* (Neal) and then switched to a new room, yet that users response appears in my 'preview' for the 'other rooms you're in' **if he is also talking in them**.

Note: My ignore of Neal was mostly due to jest, this in no way is to reflect on Neal but the chat feature (I hate to ever single anyone out here).

Comment: I've notice this same problem.  I will say that one time this bug allowed me to see a fellow I was frustrated with apologize to me (not knowing that I was ignoring him).  I'm guessing that's the exception not the rule, however.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing, came here to report it, and found this. I think this should be a `bug` rather than a `feature-request`; I have edited the tag, but I will not oppose a rollback if any think otherwise.

Answer (score -9):

Meh, this seems like a very, *very* minor intrusion. If you don't care too much about the second room, well, glancing at the sidebar and seeing "TrollUser: blah blah blah" takes only a fraction of a second. If you do care a lot about the second room, you'll have it open in another tab anyways.

I even supported [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112661/im-getting-notified-of-chat-messages-from-ignored-users), but you gotta draw the line somewhere.

Comment: I like to only keep one tab open and use the sidebar to jump rooms or look for new posts at a glance  .. which is why i notice this

Comment: Okay, but it's a clear software bug. That annoys me more than seeing the ignored user's message!

Comment: "(...) you gotta draw the line somewhere." Can we draw the line at the point where you can't see messages from ignored users anymore? :P

Comment: This is still an issue, and still a bug. If the last message shown in this list is to have any use, it should not show messages I expressively *don't want to read*.

Comment: Note that this also applies to "AnnoyingBot" or "UnnecessaryBlogFeed" in addition to "TrollUser". I would expect consistent behavior of "ignore" across the entire chat interface.

Comment: I recently saw this happening as well. Ignoring for me means ignoring and not: "Yeah you might have a glimps on them from time to time...". Would be happy if this could be fixed.